# Commenting on a comment

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a commenting system, and I want to let users to comment on an existent comment.

I created a link for each comment to be able to click on it to be redirected to the form to write an answer to an existent comment. When the form will be submitted, a hidden input should take to current id of the existent comment. But there is a problem: the id of each comment is available in a while loop but as soon as the loop is done, the variable disappears. So I would like to know how to get the id of each comment to send it in a hidden input.

Here my full code:

```
<h2>Fiche</h2>

<?php

$_SESSION['cf']['message'] = $_GET['message'];

$reponse = db_query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = ?', array($_SESSION['cf']['message']));
$donneesmsg = $reponse->fetch()

?>


<h5><?php echo $donneesmsg['Pseudo']; ?></h5>

<p class="text-center text-align"><?php echo $donneesmsg['Message']; ?></p>

<a href="index.php?page=fiche&message=<?php echo $_SESSION['cf']['message'] ?>&#formcom">Repondre</a>

<?php

    echo '<h4>Commentaires</h4>';
    echo '<hr>';

            $reponse1 = db_query('SELECT * FROM comment WHERE messages_id = ?', array($donneesmsg['id']));
            $donneescom1 = $reponse1->fetch();

$reponse = db_query('SELECT * FROM comment WHERE messages_id = ? ORDER BY id ASC', array($donneesmsg['id']));
while ($donneescom = $reponse->fetch()) {


    if ($donneescom['commentaires_id'] == 0) 

        {

            echo '<center>';
            echo '' .$donneescom['id']. '<br>';
            echo '' .$donneescom['pseudo']. '<br>';
            echo '' .$donneescom['commentaire']. '<br>';
            echo '<a href="index.php?page=fiche&message=' .$_SESSION['cf']['message']. '&com=' .$donneescom['id']. '#formcom">Repondre</a>';
            echo '<hr>';
            echo '</center>';


        }


    if ($donneescom['commentaires_id'] != 0)
        {

            echo 'En reponse au com ' .$donneescom['commentaires_id']. '<br>';
            echo '' .$donneescom['id']. '<br>';
            echo '' .$donneescom['pseudo']. '<br>';
            echo '' .$donneescom['commentaire']. '<br>';
            echo '<a href="index.php?page=fiche&message=' .$_SESSION['cf']['message']. '&com=' .$donneescom['id']. '#formcom">Repondre</a>';
            echo '<hr>';



        }
    }

    $reponse1 = db_query('SELECT * FROM comment WHERE messages_id = ?', array($donneesmsg['id']));
    $donneescom1 = $reponse1->fetch();

?>


<form id="formcom" method="post" action="index.php?page=addcomment">
Pseudo: <input type="text" placeholder="Pseudo" name="pseudo"> <br>
Mail: <input type="email" placeholder="Mail" name="mail"> <br>
Commentaire: <textarea  placeholder="Commentaire" name="commentaire"></textarea> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo time(); ?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="messages_id" value="<?php echo $donneesmsg['id']; ?>"><br>           
<input type="text" name="commentaires_id" value="<?php echo $donneescom1['id']; ?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $donneesmsg['id']; ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
</form>
```

Comment: I am starting in PHP, so I don't really understand what do you mean by "SQL joins".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reply link looks like it puts the comment ID to reply to into the `GET` parameter `com`. Therefore, when you output the comment form, you should check to see if the `com` parameter exists, and if it does, output a hidden `input` with that ID in it.

Comment: Actually the GET parameter for com existe while i am in the while loop but I can't use it in the hidden input because it doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @user2287503: You're right that `$donneescom['id']` doesn't exist any more, but you only care about that when you're generating the list of comments. When the user clicks on the link, `$_GET['com']` will be set to the `$donneescom['id']` of the comment they clicked.

Comment: And since I am with you, i just need an other info, I want to display the "child" comment just under the "parent" comment, how can I set this up ?

Comment: @user2287503: That's a little trickier. You'll need to either use recursion or some tricky database structure. I'd recommend asking a new question about that.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna that, Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating the link with the comment id rather then the message id.

A better solution would be to use a parent_id for the comment, and use that.

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the question asked. Or, if it somehow does, could you edit to make it a bit clearer how you've addressed their problem? The question looks to be about scope, or how to access a variable later. If he uses comment id, or parent_id, how will that change his problem?